# Low fps in wine/playonlinux, not changing after changing settings

Tags: ati, graphics, wine, playonlinux

When I'm playing a game in wine/playonlinux my fps are kinda low.
In LoL I had about 180fps on highest settings on windows. Guild Wars 2 was working fine on windows too. There I had about 50 to 60fps (35 when in a huge zerg) when the graphics were maxed out. 
Now I have in LoL only 28-45 on **both** lowest and highest settings. I changed the resolution too, didnt do anything. Same thing  for gw2 (~20fps@1280x800 maxed, ~20fps@1024x768 lowest). It seems to doesnt matter what setting I use, I'll always get kinda low fps. I also tried to overclock my graphics card which had no improvements at all.
But in the process of doing that I observed that (at least in gw2, lol not tested because I cant switch to another window) my card isnt fully used when I set the settings to the lowest. It uses in gw2 only 300MHz core and 150MHz memory clock and a gpu load of about 30% to 60%. When I use the highest setting the card is running at 1090 MHz core and 1500MHz memory clock with a gpu load of around 60% to 90%.

My guess is that the drivers from AMD are at fault but I couldnt find ( or I am to stupid to) the facts to support that theory.
Has anyone an idea what I might do to fully use my gpu?

Specs:
MSIs AMD R9 270 2G 2GB graphics card,
Inteln Xeon 1230v3@3.41GHz,
8GB DDR3@1600,
Ubuntu 14.04. 64bit,
Playonlinux v4.2.5,
LoL Wine 1.7.33,
GW2 Wine 1.7.1,
Catalyst 13.35

Edit: I tried out some benchmarks and downloaded DOTA2 for test. The results are as I would expect from a R9 270, so it has to be wine? 
I dont expect the fps to ramp up like 20fps but why is there no difference when I go from highest settings to lowest setting?

Answer (score 1):

WINE acts as a software layer between game and the operating system, thereby reducing speed. The problem is bound to exist. Only very high end cards can work well.

I suggest you try out steam games on linux, see if LOL and GW2 are available for linux. I run CS:CZ, CS:GO on ubuntu via steam and they run smoothly.

Comment: The problem isnt with my card. As I've written above the card isnt used to its full potential at all. Also I've read about people getting higher fps.
I'm now downloading DOTA2 for the test. I also tried some benchmarks (furmark, gimark, pixmark) and was getting good fps, as I would expect from the r9 270

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did a lot of gaming with(long back though) wine/playonlinux, on Ubuntu with my onboard HD 4250, the only issue I face was the characters in some games were not drawn, they were visible as black figures. No FPS drops or anything as such. The key is getting the right drivers with correct `xorg` dependences. Also AMD has been a little slow in maintaining their driver support, so if R9 270 is really new then you'll have to wait. Also now I'm using R7 250 on Arch linux and I get FPS drops.